# Launch JavaScript function from HTML div where function name is generated dynamically ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamic, dynamic-function

I generate javascript function name dynamically like this:

```
<script>
        function mouseOver<%= _@special.ObjectId %>() {
            //do stuff;
        }
</script>
```

And later I need to launch this function from html, but nothing happens:

```
<div onmouseover='mouseOver" + _@special.ObjectId +"()' />
```

I guess I am calling it in wrong way. 
BTW, the @special.ObjectId is a number taken from Model and it is not null. How can I call the function here?

Comment: Why is there the need to create the function name dynamically?

Comment: I am looking for option to controll different divs behaviors. you suggest to use one function I guess

Comment: It really depends on what your needs are. But if you attribute your div with data/ids then I can't see why one function would be a problem

Comment: you are right, I was looking at this problem from wrong angle. I forgot that JS works on same principles as the languages I know, so I will pass the ID to the single function and work on it from there. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

When we have the similar problem, we followed this way to invoke dynamic script.

```
<script>
function mouseOver(id) {
        //do stuff;
}
</script>

<div onmouseover='mouseOver(" + _@special.ObjectId +")' />
```

Hope this helps.!

Comment: that is very helpful! I am wrapping my head around to get it to work.

Comment: I think that quotes need to be escaped (or replaced by double quotes) on your example: `onmouseover='mouseOver(\" + _@special.ObjectId +\")'`.